# List users which have not connected by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table login like below :

| Idlogin | userid. | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 12A. | 22/03/2021 |
| 2. | 12B. | 22/04/2021 |
| 3. | 12A. | 29/03/2021 |

I have a table users that contains a list of all the users

| Iduser |
| --- |
| 12A |
| 12B |
| 23k |
| Jk8 |
| Kl9 |

And a table dimdates that contains all dates from 2018

| Date |
| --- |
| 01/01/2018 |
| 02/01/2018 till now |

I need to list all users that have not connected in all the dates available in the table date

Comment: Also specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: i added an answer , but i didnt test it, please add some sql fiddle so people can test their result for your better solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cartesian Join** to list all users with all dates and use **NOT EXIST** to exclude the rows using login table:

```
select u.Iduser, d.date from 
dimdates d,
users u
where not exists 
(
select 1 from login l
where l.date = d.date
and l.Idlogin=u.Iduser
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Anti-semi join:

```
select * 
from [users] U
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from [login] L
    inner join dimdates D on L.[Date]=D.[Date]
    where L.Idlogin=U.Iduser
)
```

Comment: I'm looking to display userid and date. Because an user can connect for example 01/01/2021 and not connected 01/03/2021

Comment: So you want to see every possible user-date login that didn't happen? That will be a lot of rows, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. This is what i'm looking for it.